# Xamarin.IOS: UITableViewSource crashes on device

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, uitableview, xamarin

I've a very simple app which contains only **UITableView** and its **UITableViewSource**..

When using UITableView without linking to UITableViewSource (the app **works in simulator & device**)

But when I link the UITableView to the UITableViewSource (the app **works in simulator** but **crashes on device**)

( The device is **iPad** running IOS 9.2.1 )

it gives me this long error:

```
2016-02-08 05:16:02.913 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical: Stacktrace:

2016-02-08 05:16:02.913 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
2016-02-08 05:16:02.915 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
2016-02-08 05:16:02.915 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],intptr,intptr) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2689/962a0506/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:77
2016-02-08 05:16:02.916 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2689/962a0506/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:60
2016-02-08 05:16:02.916 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   at secondApp.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00008] in /Users/Mujtaba/Desktop/XamarinProjects/secondApp/secondApp/Main.cs:12
2016-02-08 05:16:02.917 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_dynamic (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0xffffffff>
2016-02-08 05:16:02.917 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical: 
Native stacktrace:

2016-02-08 05:16:02.982 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   0   secondApp                           0x0027ffb5 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 240
2016-02-08 05:16:02.982 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   1   secondApp                           0x00286243 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 226
2016-02-08 05:16:02.983 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x20f3385f _sigtramp + 42
2016-02-08 05:16:02.983 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   3   secondApp                           0x00323310 xamarin_stret_trampoline + 96
2016-02-08 05:16:02.984 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   4   UIKit                               0x25479d29 <redacted> + 2976
2016-02-08 05:16:02.984 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   5   UIKit                               0x2547907b <redacted> + 378
2016-02-08 05:16:02.984 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   6   UIKit                               0x25478e2d <redacted> + 56
2016-02-08 05:16:02.985 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   7   UIKit                               0x25478c33 <redacted> + 314
2016-02-08 05:16:02.985 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   8   UIKit                               0x256d4293 <redacted> + 42
2016-02-08 05:16:02.985 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   9   UIKit                               0x2547f295 <redacted> + 128
2016-02-08 05:16:02.986 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   10  UIKit                               0x25391369 <redacted> + 1480
2016-02-08 05:16:02.986 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   11  UIKit                               0x253b5fd5 <redacted> + 68
2016-02-08 05:16:02.986 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   12  UIKit                               0x253910ab <redacted> + 778
2016-02-08 05:16:02.987 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   13  UIKit                               0x253907ed <redacted> + 124
2016-02-08 05:16:02.987 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   14  UIKit                               0x2539069b <redacted> + 426
2016-02-08 05:16:02.987 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   15  UIKit                               0x2539d713 <redacted> + 1658
2016-02-08 05:16:02.987 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   16  UIKit                               0x2539d08f <redacted> + 30
2016-02-08 05:16:02.988 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   17  UIKit                               0x2539c87d <redacted> + 496
2016-02-08 05:16:02.988 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   18  UIKit                               0x25399bf3 <redacted> + 278
2016-02-08 05:16:02.988 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   19  UIKit                               0x2540e915 <redacted> + 48
2016-02-08 05:16:02.989 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   20  UIKit                               0x2563311d <redacted> + 3320
2016-02-08 05:16:02.989 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   21  UIKit                               0x25636f0f <redacted> + 1570
2016-02-08 05:16:02.989 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   22  UIKit                               0x2564ac15 <redacted> + 36
2016-02-08 05:16:02.989 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   23  UIKit                               0x256343f7 <redacted> + 134
2016-02-08 05:16:02.990 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   24  FrontBoardServices                  0x2250fc75 <redacted> + 232
2016-02-08 05:16:02.990 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   25  FrontBoardServices                  0x2250ff61 <redacted> + 44
2016-02-08 05:16:02.990 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   26  CoreFoundation                      0x211c1257 <redacted> + 14
2016-02-08 05:16:02.990 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   27  CoreFoundation                      0x211c0e47 <redacted> + 454
2016-02-08 05:16:02.990 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   28  CoreFoundation                      0x211bf1af <redacted> + 806
2016-02-08 05:16:02.991 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   29  CoreFoundation                      0x21111bb9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
2016-02-08 05:16:02.991 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   30  CoreFoundation                      0x211119ad CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
2016-02-08 05:16:02.991 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   31  UIKit                               0x25403a17 <redacted> + 526
2016-02-08 05:16:02.991 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   32  UIKit                               0x253fdfb5 UIApplicationMain + 144
2016-02-08 05:16:02.992 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   33  secondApp                           0x000f4044 wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 272
2016-02-08 05:16:02.992 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   34  secondApp                           0x000bd130 UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr + 52
2016-02-08 05:16:02.992 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   35  secondApp                           0x000bd0f0 UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 204
2016-02-08 05:16:02.992 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   36  secondApp                           0x000b714c secondApp_Application_Main_string__ + 188
2016-02-08 05:16:02.992 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   37  secondApp                           0x002101b4 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 256
2016-02-08 05:16:02.993 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   38  secondApp                           0x0028888f mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1150
2016-02-08 05:16:02.993 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   39  secondApp                           0x002c71f5 mono_runtime_invoke + 88
2016-02-08 05:16:02.993 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   40  secondApp                           0x002ca64b mono_runtime_exec_main + 282
2016-02-08 05:16:02.993 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   41  secondApp                           0x00332fa4 xamarin_main + 2072
2016-02-08 05:16:02.994 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   42  secondApp                           0x0025aac5 main + 112
2016-02-08 05:16:02.994 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical:   43  libdyld.dylib                       0x20dc4873 <redacted> + 2
2016-02-08 05:16:02.994 secondApp[4487:1711787] critical: 
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

All my project contain just 2 views :)

**ViewController.cs** :

```
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace secondApp
{
    public partial class ViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public ViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();

            string[] list = new string[]{"Red", "Blue", "Brown", "Green" };

            UITableView table = new UITableView {
                Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect (0, 0, View.Bounds.Width, View.Bounds.Height),

                Source = new myTableSource(list)   // the problem happens when I add this line
            };

            View.AddSubview (table);

        }

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
        {
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();
        }
    }
}
```

and **myTableSource.cs** :

```
using System;
using UIKit;

namespace secondApp
{
    public class myTableSource : UITableViewSource
    {
        string[] TableItems;
        string CellIdentifier = "TableCell";

        public myTableSource (string[] items)
        {
            TableItems = items;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            return TableItems.Length;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (CellIdentifier);
            string item = TableItems[indexPath.Row];

            if (cell == null){
                cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier);
            }

            cell.TextLabel.Text = item;

            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope there is a simple solution for this error, because I still in the first step in learning **Xamarin**

Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Can you please dy symbolise this crash log ?

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean @aman.sood

Comment: @Mujtaba Fathel after resymbolication you can see function real names in your stacktrace instead of address and offset `UIKit 0x25479d29 <redacted> + 2976`

Comment: Here is the link that can help you https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1969488--where-can-i-find-the-dsym-file-to-symbolicate-ios-crash-logs- . Without symbolication you can't understand stack trace correctly because you can't see stack of called functions, and each crash will be a problem for you, like this one with table view.

Comment: I don't know why .. But today (after almost a week) the problem has gone by itself, the same solution works perfectly on the same device without any edits :)

Comment: I only did (Biuld -> Clean All) .. maybe it solved the problem, or maybe the problem was solved by just waiting for a week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After almost a week the problem has gone by itself, the **same solution** works perfectly on the **same device**  ...

I only did `Build -> Clean All` .. maybe it solved the problem, or maybe the problem was solved by just waiting for a week